# adding typeScript Definitions (d.ts) for angularjs immediately breaks VS 2015

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am trying to add Typescript to a VS 2015 MVC project but as soon as I use NuGet to install  angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped version="6.5.6" my build breaks with hundreds of errors in the jquery.d.ts file. The only changes to my packages.config are listed below -

Is it that I am missing something or that I need to adjust some configuration file? I have been googling this but haven't found anything that helps.

It's worth noting that I discarded all of my changes and started with a fresh copy of the repo that built just fine, the only thing I did was use the package manager to install angularjs typescript.

```
<package id="jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped" version="0.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped" version="6.5.6" targetFramework="net461" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I just figured this out after much pain, I removed everything and then installed jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped first as I noticed there was a newer version however for some reason I could not update it through the NuGet package manager.

If you install angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped first it will install this seemingly ancient version of jquery - the version installed now is 3.1.2.

Hope this is useful to someone.